# React native android API request only work when connected to debugger and enabled network inspect.(on iOS works fine)

Tags: android, react-native

I have a weird issue with making Axios requests to my API on Android (using Android studio for building). In the dev build as well as the release build Axios does not work. As soon as I power up React Native Debugger and enable Enable Network Inspect the requests work.

that too only happening on android,  on IOS everything working fine.

As i tried to console the error it gives is **status code 403**

Comment: Can you give more details? What requests are you sending in both cases? Have you checked headers?